# Xamarin tutorial FindViewByID returns null on disabled controls

Tags: null, xamarin.android, findviewbyid

I'm new to Xamarin development so I started by following instructions on Xamarin's  "Hello Android" (multi-screen) tutorial, everything was fine until I got to this instruction:

```
Button callHistoryButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.CallHistoryButton);
```

Anybody knows why this method returns null when CallHistoryButton.Enabled = false?

Xamarin's tutorial was very specific, but this behavior drove me nuts until I found out my code was throwing errors because the control was disabled.

I've been testing on Nexus 4(Kitkat) emulator.

Comment: how did u assign the id to the button in axml file?

Comment: Are you sure this works if that button is enabled?

Comment: you could provide link to this tutorial, if it happens to be online ( what isn't nowdays )

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you saved all changes to your xaml layout file and also do a rebuild on your code. What is the error that you are getting? Also what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but project's working now, I could swear that what I saw was directly linked to ".enabled" value. I'm working on VS Community 2015, Tutorial is for Android.Xamarin.